# Rocket.Chat on Ubuntu 16.04 + Apache2 SSL Proxy not working

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, apache2

Problem: Rocket.Chat Server runs perfectly over HTTP, but unfortunately I can't get it to work with HTTPS and Apache2 Reverse Proxy...

Apache-Config sub.example.com (Rocket.Chat):

```
> <VirtualHost IP:443>
> 
> ServerAdmin webmaster@sub.example.com
> ServerName sub.example.com
> ServerAlias www.sub.example.com
> ErrorLog /var/log/chat.sub.example.com_error.log
> TransferLog /var/log/chat.sub.example.com_access.log
> LogLevel info
> SSLEngine On
> SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.example.com/fullchain.pem
> SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.example.com/privkey.pem
> 
> <Location />
>         Order allow,deny
>         Allow from all
> </Location>
> 
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
> RewriteRule /(.*) ws://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade}           !=websocket [NC]
> RewriteRule /(.*) http://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]
> 
> ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
> </VirtualHost>
```

On top runs example.com which also serves other content via https:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]


  </VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Caddy-Files looks like this:

```
> https://sub.example.com
> proxy / localhost:3000 {
>   websocket
>   transparent
> }
```

Caddy-Status (Everytime I edit the default caddy-file to the settings above the service seems to fail):

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/26794734/24507484/def39ce6-1560-11e7-8233-265c5a833b39.png

Summary (/./ --> Link-Removal):

> [Website] HTTPS https:/./example.com --> Working
>
> [Rocket.Chat] HTTP http:/./sub.example.com:3000 --> Working
>
> [Rocket.Chat] HTTPS https:/./sub.example.com:3000
>   --> NOT WORKING (ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED)

Is anyone able to give me a hint? I think it is a problem with to top domain and the VirtualHosts...
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same trouble with centos7 and apache, resolved by installing intermediate certificate! Seems mobile API needed it. Test your server SSL with 
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html.
If you get a "chain incomplete" error in certificate test, use https://certificatechain.io/ to resolve it.

Paste on the last site your actual ssl certificate, and use the result for your intermediate certificate. Restart httpd, another test in ssllabs must look OK in certificate chain and mobile application sounds good.